# not able to select the dependent dropdown value in selenium

Tags: selenium

system is giving me unable to locate element error message 
scenario is i have to select the occupation list which contains values like salaried, self employed(Business) , Self employed(Professional)etc.. on the basis of which the value values will be populated in next dropdown list  i am using below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-ED_EmpType-container")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Salaried']")).click();
```

the above code is working for other dropdowns bt not working for this dropdown
properties of this dropdown

```html
<ul id="select2-ED_EmpType-results" class="select2-results__options" role="tree" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
<li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> Please select... </li>
<li id="select2-ED_EmpType-result-nhlf-Salaried" class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true"> Salaried </li>
```

Comment: try //*[constains(text(), 'Salaried')]

Comment: Why not use the id provided?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is space in your string use below xpath

```
//li[normalize-space() ='Salaried']
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the option item **`Salaried`** you can use either of the following line of code :

- **`cssSelector`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.select2-results__option#select2-ED_EmpType-result-nhlf-Salaried")).click();
  ```
- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[class='select2-results__option' and id='select2-ED_EmpType-result-nhlf-Salaried']")).click();
  ```